# Does $\mathbb{P}(X_1 > a) \leq \delta$ imply $\mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{J} \sum_{i=1}^J X_i > a \right ) \leq \delta$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_J$ be identically distributed random variables.

*Edit: may assume independence as well as finite expectation of the $X_i$'s above.*

Does $\mathbb{P}(X_1 > a) \leq \delta$ imply $\mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{J} \sum_{i=1}^J X_i > a \right ) \leq \delta$ ?

Answer (score 4):

1: No, this isn't true.  Let $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, \dots, J\}$ and let $X_i = c \cdot 1_{\{Y = i\}}$ for some $c$. Then $P(X_1 > 0) = 1/J$ and $\frac{1}{J} \sum_{i=1}^J X_i = c/J$ a.s., so the claim is false if $0 < a < c/J$ and $1/J < \delta < 1$.

Comment: Can the claim be true if the $X_i$'s are independent?

Comment: @ironX: It's still not.  Imagine $X_i$ with a distribution that takes a very large value with very small probability, so that $E[X_i] > a$.  Then as $J \to \infty$ the weak law of large numbers says that $P(\frac{1}{J} \sum^J X_i > a)$ approaches 1.

Comment: related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134153/does-averaging-of-random-variables-always-improve-concentration