# Does averaging of random variables always improve concentration?

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1^{(n)}, X_2^{(n)}, ..., X_J^{(n)}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables satisfying

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left [ X_i^{(n)} \right ] &\leq a_n \tag1\\
\mathbb{P} \left( X_i^{(n)} \geq a_n + \frac{\log(n)}{n}  \right) &\leq e^{-n}  \tag2
\end{align}
for all $i \in \{1, ..., J \}$.

**Intuition**: As $n \to \infty$, the concentration of $X_i^{(n)}$ around its mean  increases. Moreover, by the law of large numbers, the concentration of $$\frac{1}{J}\sum_{i=1}^J X_i^{(n)}$$
will *doubly* increase as $n$ and $J$ both become large. Therefore, one expects that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{1}{J}\sum_{i=1}^J X_i^{(n)} \geq a_n + \frac{\log(n)}{n}  \right) &\leq  e^{-n} 
\end{align}
Furthermore, if I let $J = J(n)$ be an increasing function of $n$, I expect

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{1}{J}\sum_{i=1}^J X_i^{(n)} \geq a_n + \frac{\log(n)}{n}  \right) &\leq  o\left( e^{-n} \right) 
\end{align}
where $o(e^{-n})$ represents faster decay than $e^{-n}$.

Is my intuition correct? If yes, how to formalize this?

Comment: What does the superscript $(n)$ mean? Is it a power or second index?

Comment: it is a second index.